# Function and its inverse in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove that : if $L \subseteq M,$  then $f^{-1}(L) \subseteq f^{-1}(M)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you advance

> $$ x \in f^{-1}(L)\implies f(x) \in L \implies f(x)\in M \implies x\in f^{-1}(M) \implies L \subset M.$$

You should know how to justify the steps in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The basic property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ is
$$
x \in f^{-1}[Y] \;\equiv\; f(x) \in Y
$$
So let's take our proof goal, use the definitions and this basic property, and see where that leads us:
\begin{align}
& f^{-1}[L] \;\subseteq\; f^{-1}[M] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in f^{-1}[L] \;\Rightarrow\; x \in f^{-1}[M] \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the above basic property, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: f(x) \in L \;\Rightarrow\; f(x) \in M \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"..."} \\
\end{align}
Now use the assumption $\;L \subseteq M\;$, or in other words $\;\langle \forall y :: y \in L \;\Rightarrow\; y \in M \rangle\;$, and complete the proof.